# Why is some of my Java code being ignored? Issue: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, algorithm

My code sample:

```
public class arrray_2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateArray();

    }
    public static void populateArray(){
        int [] numbers = new int [131071];
        HashSet<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 131071; i++) {
                int num = (int)(Math.random() * 131072 ); 
                while (used.contains(num)) { 
                    num = (int) (Math.random() * 131072 ); 
                }
                used.add(num);
                numbers[i] = num;
}
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        for (int element : numbers) {
            System.out.println(numbers[element]);

        }
        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
            if (numbers[x]+1 != numbers[x+1] ) {
                System.out.println("Missing Number is: "+numbers[x]);

            }

        }
        System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }
```

By executing this I come up with this error:

> **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

This is my code I'm using and for some reason, the code after the for (int : element) is being ignored and I don't know why.

Comment: Show the output which you get.

Comment: The array will print out but won't display the missing number.

Comment: In second for loop. `System.out.println(numbers[element])` you should print out _element_ not _numbers[element]_ since you're iterating over the values not the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERROR**

You have a logic error to the last for the statement. You are saying:

```
if (numbers[x]+1 != numbers[x+1] )
```

The numbers length is 131071. By saying numbers[x+1] means that it will try to compare the position of 131071+1 = 131072 something that is out of bounds. Do you see the error? You said in the beginning that you want an array of 131071 positions and you try to compare for the 131072nd something that does not exist.

**TIP**

You must replace also this:

```
System.out.println(numbers[element]);
```

with this:

```
System.out.println(element);
```

That is why you use this kind of for statement. Otherwise, you need to use the classic/default one.

**SOLUTION**

You are missing a **`+1`** in your if statement. Insert it and it will be fixed.